# Что лучше использовать margin-top или margin-bottom?

Tags: css

Тут возник у меня один вопрос в голове. Почему на некоторых сайтах кто-то использует для отступов margin-top а кто-то margin-bottom. Что лучше использовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему иногда чешут затылок правой рукой, а иногда левой? Что лучше использовать?

Comment: Кул шутки, думаю тебе не сюда.

Comment: Вопрос у вас из той же серии....Видимо всё зависит от ситуации и предпочтение только одному- не есть правильный выбор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы спрашиваете как делать промежутки между соседними элементами: для этого можно либо задать `margin-bottom` верхнему элементу, либо `margin-top` нижнему.

Разумеется, какого-то секретного правила в этом вопросе не существует. Используйте то, что вам удобнее. Единственное, о чём нужно помнить - окружающие элементы.
Представим, что у вас есть три блока:

1. Без отступов.
2. С отступами сверху и снизу.
3. Без отступов.

Если по какой-то причине исчезнет второй блок, то первый и третий сольются. Иногда - это желаемое поведение, но чаще всего нет.

Правильнее будет сделать так:

1. Отступ снизу.
2. Отступ снизу.
3. Без отступов.

Или так:

1. Без отступов.
2. Отступ сверху.
3. Отступ сверху.

Таким образом, визуально страница не развалится, если какие-то элементы с неё пропадут. Главное - быть последовательным и логичным в своём выборе. Ну и помнить о том, что визуально элементы могут быть одноуровневыми, а в разметке - вложенными в другие элементы. В этом случае может понадобиться поставить отступ обёртке, а не самим элементам.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от задачи, которая стоит перед разработчиком. Если вам нужен отступ сверху, то необходимо использовать свойство `margin-top`, если же не обойтись без отступа снизу, то следует использовать `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Правило хорошего тона при вёрстке использовать `margin-bottom`, а не `margin-top`.

Comment: Андрей, а можете указать, на чем основано это суждение? Впервые слышу об этом "правиле хорошего тона".

Comment: Поддерживаю. Есть такое "внегласное" правило. Правильнее использовать `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Если такое правило действительно существует (я тоже о нём не слышал), нужно пояснить чем оно обосновано. Я могу это объяснить разве что тем, что мы анализируем страницу снизу вверх, а отступ самое последнее свойство по важности, но контраргументы можно привести ровно такие же.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, поясните тогда, пожалуйста, вы, откуда услышали об этом правиле? Любые соглашения по оформлению кода обычно фиксируется в неком своде правил.

Comment: Я скажу, откуда взялось правило. При код-ревью, когда происходит какой-то конфликт, при котором у спорящих сторон есть равные аргументы, тратится очень много времени. Чтобы избежать этого, во всех компаниях есть свой code-style - документ со всеми правилами написания кода в их конторе. В конце концов люди привыкают к такому стилю, забывают о документе, а правило становится негласным. По какому же принципу формируется правило, если аргументы спорящих сторон равны? Да просто рандомом. Так что иной разработчик вполне может сказать, что правильнее использовать `margin-top` ибо хороший тон

Comment: @VenZell, от других верстальщиков с большим опытом работы.

Comment: @P.Ilyin, мне кажется, вы попали в точку.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, если P.Ilyin прав, то правила, принятые внутри компании, не могут быть аргументом для ответа, потому что это будет ответ основанный не на знаниях, а на мнении.

Comment: @P.Ilyin, вопрос же не в том, зачем нужно правило (тут вы правы), а в том, почему именно bottom, а не top?

Comment: дык, в моем последем сообщении есть ответ и на этот вопрос: "да просто рандомом"