# Оцените пожалуйста качество вёрстки

Tags: css, инспекция-кода

Выполнил небольшую начальную разметку, с использованием flexbox. Напишите пожалуйста, насколько всё правильно, и что нужно переделать или вообще убрать (я новичок). Заранее спасибо всем за ответы!!!

https://codepen.io/Krutov/pen/bLJKQR

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px 15px blue;
    background-color: burlywood;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
}

.header{
    width: 880px;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer{
    width: 880px;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.left_sidebar{
    display: flex;
    width: 140px;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}

.content{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 580px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: chocolate;
    flex-grow: 2;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.right_sidebar{
    display: flex;
    width: 140px;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}

div{
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

div:not(.wrapper){
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>

    <div class="left_sidebar">
        LEFT_SIDEBAR
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        CONTENT
    </div>

    <div class="right_sidebar">
        RIGHT_SIDEBAR
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Расползлось при ширине сниппета...

Comment: А можно чуть чуть подробнее)) (я новичёк).

Comment: Чтобы оценить, правильно ли верстка реализована, должно быть четкое описание того, чего автор хотел добить...  О некоторых неверных решениях, Саша Вдодович, уже отметил в своем ответе, хотя не не со всем согласен в его ответе... Советую переформулировать вопрос...

Comment: Понял Вас! Благодарю)

Comment: А почему вы не использовали семантические теги, такие как `main`, `header` и  `footer`? Для доступности интерфейсов очень важна семантика))

Answer (score 3):

```
height: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
```

Бесполезно, достаточно просто `height: 100vh`

```
.header{
    width: 880px;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Достаточно будет и  `width: 100%` и `margin-bottom: 10px;` также плохая практика, лучше уж `margin-top:10px` у контента.

```
   div{
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}
```

Лучше эти атрибуты оставить в body, просто представь: у тебя появился .
И вот еще: постоянно использовать `<div>` - плохая практика, прочитай про семантику.
Например [тут](https://html5book.ru/html5-semantic-elements/)

**P.S. прошу не кидать палками, я также пока учусь как и ТС. Как говорят, чем смог.**

**P.S. Удачи тебе в твоих начинаниях!**

Comment: Почему собсна [`margin-bottom`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576251/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-margin-top-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-margin-bottom) "плохая практика"?

Comment: Классно! такая оценка и анализ - это то что мне нужно! А если оставить height: 100vh, высота ведь и так будет увеличиваться при необходимости, правильно?

Comment: Кстати, если делаю width: 100% у .header, то при сужении страницы, он просто уменьшается очень сильно, а если crjv,bybhjdfnm c % и px, блоки все послушно перескакивают вниз, и нет полосы прокрутки.

Comment: height:100vh  - высота равна высоте екрана  
Детальней: https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units
Второе предложения не понял.
Как по мне, margin-bottom у хедера так себе уже потому, что "а зачем он там нужен то" ??

Comment: margin-bottom у хедера чтобы отделить его от контента на 10 px. Во втором предложении (извините что не так написал) я имел ввиду если скомбинировать проценты и пиксели то блок более послушный, и нет полосы прокрутки

Comment: а если не margin-bottom, то как отделить от контента хедер? (подскажите пожалуйста, может я что то не учёл)

Comment: Не могу быть на 100% увереным, я также учусь, но как по мне, гораздо лаконичней будет отделить контент от хедера, а не наоборот. У контента margin-top:10px; или padding. По поводу хедера, представь себе на маленьком екране хедер шириной в 800px. Беда. Такие елементы как хедеры футеры и т.д. всегда должны быть в %. По поводу прокрутки: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/shirina-bloka (причина ее появления). Используй normalize.css, и твоя жизнь станет гораздо прекрасней.  О ней: https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/64-about-normalize-css Сообственно, она: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Благодарю за дельные советы. А если для хедера и футера использовать медиа-запросы, это ведь уменьшит указанную ширину при уменьшении экрана?

Comment: Конечно. Но зачем: оставляя % оно итак будет адаптивным, если тебе нужны отступы как на макете: width:80%; margin-left:10%; Кстати, я думаю тебе будет полезно посмотреть на реальную вёрстку. Много вопросов отпадут сами собой когда увидишь вёрстку на практике. К примеру: https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D6l3ZSOQKE5g&ved=0ahUKEwjJ4dH6mdHZAhXHOSwKHdUDB0oQo7QBCCMwAA&usg=AOvVaw3TYiIWUz-3EnSLsifD7s-6

Comment: И есть есть youtube-каналы неплохие, с разеснием теории + практической вёрсткой. К примеру: ХаудиХо, Web design master и другие. Очень советую. Удачи тебе :)